# Excel 2007, Pull data from sheet 1 to sheet 2 based on changing row #

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I've created a call log worksheet with various data for my condo assn.
Each call is a separate row of data.
I've create a 2nd spreadsheet as a work order form.
The work Order sheet contains some but not all of the data from sheet 1 (call log).  I want the work order to be populated with some of the data on sheet 1.

I've envisioned the office person typing a row number from sheet 1 onto sheet 2 and as a result, the Work Order would be populated with the appropriate cells from that row on sheet 1.  At that point, the work order could be printed and if necessary, she could enter a new row number and the work order would now be populated with data from a different call.  I do not need the work order info kept.  I just need to be able to print it.

I cannot figure out how to do this.  I've tried concatenating but that isn't working.  HELP.  Thanks!!

After a night's sleep, I worked out a solution that works for me.  I created a pivot on sheet 2 that has sheet 1 info.  I filter the pivot for a specific value.  Whenever the office person needs a work order, she puts a 'w' into a column of the row with the data she needs.  She goes to sheet 2, refreshes the pivot and presto, the form is populated with the field we need.

Comment: I found a solution that works for me.  I'm using a pivot table on sheet 2.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Glad you were able to solve your issue. Please  post you answer below (with details) so others who read your question will know how you resolved it.